# Is it possible to find all comments in a HTML document and wrap them in a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm working with a third party system that renders content into a html document like this:

```
<!-- componentID: 1234 -->
<div class="some-class"> .... </div>

<!-- componentID: 1235 -->
<div class="another-class"> .... </div>
```

So the system renders that componentId into a comment. The system sadly provides no way for me  to pass that id as a data attribute. I am currently stuck with this.

Is it possible to find all these comments and wrap them in a div/span where they are sitting in the document? I could then access that string and grab the id with regex.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this, it grabs all comments in html file. if there is no other unrelated comments to your plan, this can do the job.

```
$(function() {
    $("*").contents().filter(function(){
        return this.nodeType == 8;
    }).each(function(i, e){
        alert(e.nodeValue);
    });
});
```

Comment: You're welcome. I'm actually still amazed that there is a way to grab comments from HTML :)

Comment: @Regent comment is also a node in DOM tree, so it is possible to grab it like any other node.

Answer (score 8):

I will post non jQuery solution and much more efficient then traversing the whole DOM tree:

```
var x = document.evaluate('//comment()', document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null),
    comment = x.iterateNext();

while (comment) {
    alert(comment.textContent);
    comment = x.iterateNext();
}
```

However this solution is not for IE, which doesn't implement `document.evaluate` methods, that's why be aware and use it only if you don't have to support IE.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/z6GU3/

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the comments using a function like this:

```
var $comments = [];
$("*").contents().filter(function() {
    return $(this)[0].nodeName == "#comment";
}).each(function() {
    $comments.push($(this));
});

console.log($comments);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Whre/Zjj3n/

Unfortunately, I do not understand what you mean by

> wrap them in a div/span where they are sitting in the document

If the comment belongs to the next element, you could directly apply it to the element: http://jsfiddle.net/Whre/Zjj3n/3/

Comment: About "wrap them in a div/span where they are sitting in the document": OP means to wrap `<!-- componentID: 1234 -->` with HTML tag to something like `<div class="toGrabComments"><!-- componentID: 1234 --></div>`. But, as you know, there is simplier way to get comments text